# Nested for-in loops to search JSON data for string matches Swift

Tags: json, swift, for-loop

I'm struggling to find a method of looping through JSON data to find string matches.  I have over 90 values in each row so I don't want to use the row[""] method I have commented out.

I get the error: Type 'Element' (aka 'AnyObject') does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'.

So I assume this is because the JSON data doesn't work with the the 
"for (key, value) in row" method I am using. All my searching has just suggested the use of row[""].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    for row in result {
        for (key,value) in row {
            //let value = row["city"] as! String
            if value.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString){
                print("\(value) matches \(searchText)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment of data (beginning and end):

```
{
0 = 469347;
1 = 20;
10 = "2015-09-16";
11 = "2015-09-18";
12 = 1;
13 = 6;
14 = "$250 free fuel against receipts";
15 = "";

....

transmission = Manual;
tv = 0;
"tyre_preassure" = "";
"unique_key" = 98fd557e5988ea0d66cfaf9cf2742789;
"vehicle_type" = "3 Berth Hitop";
"vehicle_type_id" = 219;
"waste_water" = "";
width = "";
year = "";
}
{
...
}
```

Comment: Please include a fragment of the JSON you are searching

Comment: On which key you want to searching?

Comment: I want to search through the whole set

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary only contains `String` for every key value, I don't think you need a nested loop to do this. Just try this

```
        for (key,value) in result {
            let myString = value as! String
            if myString.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString){
                print("\(myString) matches \(searchText)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey sorry I should of clarified, the fragment of data is just one of many in the data. I've got another 38 of similar structure so that's why I'm using the nested loops